# how do i enable "modifier" in blender 2.79?

Tags: modeling

I want to be able to morph some modeled pieces. I am unable to use the apply modifier control. It is disabled. I'm doing all that i can to re-enable it. Nothing is working. What am I doing wrong? How do I enable the Modifier?

Comment: Are you in edit mode? Modifiers can only be applied in object mode.

Comment: oh! i don't know. i'll look again. but each time i try to use it, it comes up with and exclamation point saying "modier disabled. i went to "user preferences" and turned on "3D modifier"

Comment: "modifier is disabled. skipping appy"

Comment: yes. i am in object mode.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: i can't do a screenshot. but, it's when i go into "modifier"  then i hit "add modifier" i choose one, then i hit "apply" it says "error" with an exclamation point. it says "modifier disabled".  i go into "user preferences" i enable the "3D Modifier" only ption i can find that says "modifier". it still doesn't turn on.